How to find a prime that is larger than some constant value and what it's time complexity
I ask this in the context of hashing where a prime greater than some constant is required
for example in universal hashing:

h(k) = [(a.k+b) mod p] mod m

a and b are random numbers
m is the size of direct access table
p is a prime that's larger than the amount of items to be mapped.
How would we find such a prime p and what whould be the time complexity of that ?

Run all numbers from 1 to INT_MAX through your function

It will depend on how much space you're prepared to use. If you know an upper bound, you could do it in constant time with a single look-up, but it would soon require a lot of space to do it that way. What's the typical and maximum size of p required?

Yeah i guess it makes sense to have a look-up even though number of items can go up to millions i think we dont need to know every prime up to that point and that we can make it work by using couple of primes.
For example: when number of my items gets to 30k i can set my prime to 108649 then when number of items exceeds that i can set my prime to 208787 and so on.
Also maybe i can use some prime that's larger than the amount of maximum possible items to mapped. But i dont know if that affects the randomness in a bad way.

Bertrand's Postulate shows that there is at least one prime number in the range n..2n. That will give an upper bound to the search.
